# Proof of the Union of Power Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I saw the proof at [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Union_of_Power_Sets). I know well that $X\in \mathcal{P}(A)\iff X\subseteq A$ where $A$ is a set, but why can't I show the following way

\begin{align}
X\in (\mathcal{P}(S)\cup \mathcal{P}(T))&\iff (X\in \mathcal{P}(S))\vee (X\in \mathcal{P}(T))\\
&\iff (X\subseteq S) \vee (X\subseteq T)\\
&\iff X\subseteq (S\cup T)\\
&\iff X\in \mathcal{P}(S\cup T),
\end{align}
or which one of the bi-implications is wrong that should be replaced by $\implies$? Note that I understood the counterexample in the link. I just want to know where the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one $(X\subseteq S) \vee (X\subseteq T)
\iff X\subseteq (S\cup T)$ should be an implication.  Let $X=\{a,b\}, S=\{a\}, T=\{b\}$ and the reverse direction is false.

Comment: Does it hold if $\vee$ is replaced by $\wedge$?

Comment: No, the same example proves it does not work.

Comment: My question wasn't too clear, but it doesn't matter anyway. It seems that I now understand it better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that $X \subseteq S \cup T$ does not imply that $X \subseteq S$ or $X \subseteq T$: the elements of $X$ could be distributed in both sets.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\require{cancel}X\subseteq (S\cup T)$ does not necessarily imply $X\subseteq S \vee X\subseteq T$.

Example: $\{1,3\}\subseteq (\{1,2\}\cup\{2,3\})$ but $\{1,3\}\not\subseteq \{1,2\} \wedge \{1,3\}\not\subseteq\{2,3\}$

Only $X\subseteq S \vee X\subseteq T\implies X\subseteq (S\cup T)$ holds in general.

Comment: You meant $\{1,3\}\not\subseteq \{1,2\} \vee \{1,3\}\not\subseteq\{2,3\}$. Thanks for answer. I upvoted it.

Comment: No, @AjmalW , I meant the conjunction.  ref: DeMorgan's Rules.